# PNGs in DIV layers getting cut off in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, png, html

Here is the test site:

http://www.bodwell.edu/summer/new_busp_11/

It looks totally fine in any browser, except of course IE.

The menu bar and title png graphics are getting cut off right at where the underlying layer is.  I have no idea how to resolve this and still keep this looking as it is in the rest of the browsers, i.e. Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc.

Help!

Comment: make sure the element that contains the meny has overflow to visible and that the z-index are accuratly set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the opacity attribute it will work. (the one below) from the **main_panel** class

```
filter: alpha(opacity=90);
```

In the meantime you can do that (perhaps have an IE specific CSS that will remove that filter).

They look similar enough in my monitor. 
You could use that yellow background image with a PNG transparency and not have that tag.

I'm unsure why IE is doing that though.

Comment: That worked!  Yes, I will probably use a png transparency instead.  Thank you very much...I was wracking my brain trying to figure that one out.